# Django LFS - custom views

Tags: django, e-commerce, django-lfs

For all those ligthning fast shop users. I'm trying to implement my own first page view that will list all products from shop ( under '/' address). So I have a template :

```
{% extends "lfs/shop/shop_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div id="najnowsze_produkty">

<ul>
{% for obj in objects %}
    <li>
        {{ obj.name }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

    </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

and then I've edited main shop view :

```
from lfs.catalog.models import Category
from lfs.catalog.models import Product

def shop_view(request, template_name="lfs/shop/shop.html"):
  products = Product.objects.all()
  shop = lfs_get_object_or_404(Shop, pk=1)
  return render_to_response(template_name, RequestContext(request, {
    "shop" : shop, "products" : products
}))
```

but it just shows nothing. When I do Product.objects.all() query in shell I get results. Any ideas what could cause the problem ? Maybe I should filter products with 'active' status only ? But I'm not sure if it can influence all objects in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're calling the context variable `products` in your view code, then referring to it as `objects` in your template. Fix them to reference the same name, and you should be good to go.

Comment: As one of the Cuban songwriters (Polito Ibáñez) said: «the small things that fulfill you» or, in Spanish, «las cosas simples que te llenan».